# Changes in the limits of the x axis time series

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I plot the following time-series, I don't know why I get eliminated the first year and also expanded to a last year (that has no data).

Code:

```
p2 <- ggplot(DB1) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Periodo, y = Participacion*100)) +
  scale_y_continuous("Participación (%)",
                     position = "right") +
  scale_x_date(name = "Año", 
               date_breaks = "year",
               date_labels = "%Y") +
  theme_cowplot()
```

See in the graph that I need year 2007 without 2020. Thanks in advance to everyone
[image: Graphic for the example]

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

### Normal code

```
plot <-
  tibble(
    x = seq.Date(from = today(),to = today() + months(48),by = "1 day"),
    y = cumsum(rnorm(1462))
         ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_line()

plot
```

[image]

### Expand - removing unnecessary spaces

```
plot + scale_x_date(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

### Custom limits

```
plot + scale_x_date(limits = dmy(c("01/01/2021","31/01/2028")))
```

[image]

Comment: I can't see it as my solution. Sorry

Comment: The code above is an example, since I did not have the original data, but you can remove the blank space to omit 2020 and extend the limit to show 2007